Conventions for article usage in mathematical writing: 'LC-functions' vs 'the LC-functions'
I'm preparing a paper on functional equations for LC-functions and I'm uncertain about the correct usage of the definite article in the title. I'm considering two options:

"Functional equation for LC-functions with even or odd modulator"
"Functional equation for the LC-functions with even or odd modulator"

My questions are:

Is there a generally accepted convention in mathematical writing regarding the use of 'the' in such titles?

Does the inclusion or omission of 'the' change the implied meaning in any subtle way that mathematicians would recognize?


I'm particularly interested in understanding if this choice might affect how the scope or generality of the work is perceived.
Any insights from experienced mathematical writers or editors would be greatly appreciated.

While I can see the grammatical logic of (2), I think that mathematical convention dictates (1).
